# What is best material for ground cover of an outdoor dog run?

Tags: dogs, german-shepherd

We want to build a dog run in the backyard for our German Shepherd pup. 
She likes to chew rocks. 
Horse stall rubber mats?
Cement blocks?

Answer (score 4):

Cement is a good option, its very easy to wash if she poops or pees/makes a mess(wash with a hose). It also prevents dogs from digging under the fence. Though instead of using blocks just fill the entire area.

Shelters in my area use cement, really convenient.

As a side note make sure that there is a shaded area so she can get out of the sun if need be :).